# Многопоточность цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

```
import openpyxl

import sys, os

from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

system = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))



Ashan = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = system + '\\parselistinstamart.xlsx')

SheetOfAshan = Ashan['test']

Lenta = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = system + '\\parselistigoodsLENTA.xlsx')

SheetOfLenta = Lenta['test']

lastAshan = SheetOfAshan.max_row


lastLenta = SheetOfLenta.max_row

x = 1
z = 1

for x in range(lastAshan):
    goods1 = SheetOfAshan.cell(row = x + 1, column = 1).value
    for z in range(lastLenta):
        goods2 = SheetOfLenta.cell(row = z + 1, column = 1).value
        # Сравниваем товары
        if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(goods1, goods2) > 75:
            linkAshan = SheetOfAshan.cell(row = x + 1, column= 2).value
            linkLenta = SheetOfLenta.cell(row = z + 1, column = 2).value

            result = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = system + '\\Result_Ashan(instamart)-Lenta(igoods).xlsx')

            SheetOfResult = result['result']

            lastrow = SheetOfResult.max_row

            SheetOfResult.cell(row = lastrow, column = 1).value = linkAshan
            SheetOfResult.cell(row = lastrow, column = 2).value = linkLenta

            print("Добавлено")

            result.save(system + '\\Result_Ashan(instamart)-Lenta(igoods).xlsx')
```

Есть у меня вот такой код, как сделать так, чтобы цикл обработался многопоточно?

Comment: Просто отправить цикл в поток или в потоках сделать сравнение элемента goods1 с каждым элементом lastLenta?

Comment: @gil9red мне кажется лучше сравнение

Answer (score 2):

Накидал пример, но не было возможности протестировать:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import os

import openpyxl
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


# Функция будет вызываться в каждом потоке
def go(row):
    goods_ashan, link_ashan = row[0]

    items = []

    for goods_lenta, link_lenta in row[1:]:
        # Сравниваем товары
        if fuzz.token_sort_ratio(goods_ashan, goods_lenta) > 75:
            items.append((link_ashan, link_lenta))
            print("Добавлено")

    return items


DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


ashan_book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=DIR + '\\parselistinstamart.xlsx')
sheet_ashan = ashan_book['test']
ashan_rows = sheet_ashan.max_row

lenta_book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=DIR + '\\parselistigoodsLENTA.xlsx')
sheet_lenta = lenta_book['test']
lenta_rows = sheet_lenta.max_row


# Структура, в которой каждый товар Ашана противопоставляется всем товарам Ленты
# Выглядит так: [(goods_ashan, link_ashan), ((goods_lenta, link_lenta)), ((goods_lenta, link_lenta)), ...]
items = []

for i in range(ashan_rows):
    goods_ashan = sheet_ashan.cell(row=i + 1, column=1).value
    link_ashan = sheet_ashan.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value

    # Первый кортеж -- что сравнивать
    row = [(goods_ashan, link_ashan)]

    # Последующие кортежи -- с чем сравнивать
    for j in range(lenta_rows):
        goods_lenta = sheet_lenta.cell(row=j + 1, column=1).value
        link_lenta = sheet_lenta.cell(row=j + 1, column=2).value

        row.append((goods_lenta, link_lenta))

    items.append(row)

# Создаем пул потоков и отправляем список на выполнение
pool = ThreadPool()

# Вернется список -- результат от каждого потока, т.е. список с списками
results = pool.map(go, items)

# Сохранение результата
result_book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=DIR + '\\Result_Ashan(instamart)-Lenta(igoods).xlsx')
sheet_result = result_book['result']
last_row = sheet_result.max_row

i = 1

for row in results:
    for link_ashan, link_lenta in row:
        sheet_result.cell(row=last_row + i, column=1).value = link_ashan
        sheet_result.cell(row=last_row + i, column=2).value = link_lenta

    i += 1

result_book.save(DIR + '\\Result_Ashan(instamart)-Lenta(igoods).xlsx')
```

Comment: Хм, сейчас запустил код, уже около 5ти минут он не находит ни одного совпадения

Comment: Смотрите что попадает в items а после в функцию go

Comment: принтую items но выдаёт []

Comment: Скажите, у вас ест возможность протестировать?

Comment: Я могу вам скинуть excel файлы откуда я беру данные.

Comment: @МаксимХалин, разве что за оплату :) Тут я помогаю бесплатно, но делать за вас все не буду. Давайте вернемся к проблеме. Поставьте `print(row)` после `items.append(row)` -- нужно убедиться данные из xlsx были вытащены. Если там есть данные и они такие какие вы ожидаете, нужно смотреть что происходит в `go`. В принципе, если вы владеете отладчиком, можно и без print'ов (мне, лично, ими обычно удобнее)

Comment: Поставил так как вы сказали, мне вывело все наименования:ссылки с таблицы с товарами igoods

Comment: Хорошо, `go` проверяли? Если нет, то выведите `print(row[0])` и `print(row[1])` они не должны быть пустыми. А перед `if` поставьте `print(goods_ashan, goods_lenta, fuzz.token_sort_ratio(goods_ashan, goods_lenta))` и убедитесь что `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` возвращает именно то, что ожидалось

Comment: `print(row[0])` `print(row[1])` Ничего не выводят

Comment: А вот это уже странно. `items` перед `results = pool.map(go, items)` точно не пустой? Или, нет ли у вас в коде еще одного `go`?

Comment: Сделал `print(items)` перед `results = pool.map(go, items)` мне вообще ничего не выводит. Нет, у меня одна функция go

Comment: Фигня какая-то что-то должно было вывести. Если бы items был пустой, то `print(items)` вывел бы `[]`